# CC-mode indentation of C++ lambda functions with a return type that has template parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, emacs, indentation, cc-mode

I am using CC-mode in Emacs that was installed with apt on Ubuntu 20.04.
It formats code as follows:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
  auto f1 = [](int a) {
              return std::vector<int>({a});
            };
  auto f2 = [](int a) -> std::vector<int> {
                                           return std::vector<int>({a});
  };
}
```

In my opinion, format for `f1` is acceptable but `f2` not.  Is there a way
to have it format `f2` as in `f1`?  Or, more preferably, as in the following,
which was achieved with CC-mode installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
  auto f1 = [](int a) {
    return std::vector<int>({a});
  };
  auto f2 = [](int a) -> std::vector<int> {
    return std::vector<int>({a});
  };
}
```

My current workaround is as follows, but not ideal:

```
  using vector_t = std::vector<int>;
  auto f2wa = [](int a) -> vector_t {
                return vector_t({a});
              };
```

Comment: Or, just use clang-format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `google-set-c-style.el` from melpa you get your preferred formatting,

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
  auto f1 = [](int a) {
    return std::vector<int>({a});
  };
  auto f2 = [](int a) -> std::vector<int> {
    return std::vector<int>({a});
  };
}
```

In general, with cc-modes, you can play around with `c-guess` to examine and set the style rules until you find what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It gets much better than before.  On my machine, google-set-c-style.el works fine for f2, but there is no effect on f1.  I also tried c-guess (starting with "emacs -q") and got the same results: f2 is indented as expected, f1 keeps the default indent.

Comment: maybe there is a difference b/w versions, what is your `cc-mode` version? I'm on 5.33.1. Also, you can select the region of interest and run `M-x c-show-syntactic-information`. Then, modify the rules of interest in `c-guess-show`, re-evaluate the shown style and use `M-x c-set-style "your-style-name"` in your buffer

Comment: The cc-mode version was 5.33.2.  After I upgraded it to 5.35, everything works as I expected (in the default setting).  Thank you for your suggestion.